# How can i check whether an android device is connected to the web?

Tags: android

How would i know whether my device is connected the web or not? How can i detect connectivity? Any sample code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android check internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First, you need permission to know whether the device is connected to the web or not. This needs to be in your manifest, in the `<manifest>` element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Next, you need to get a reference to the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

From there you need to obtain a [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) object. For most, this will mean using [ConnectivityManager. getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()):

```
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (ni == null) {
    // There are no active networks.
    return false;
}
```

From there, you just need to use one of NetworkInfo's methods to determine if the device is connected to the internet:

```
boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();
```

Comment: I get a null pointer exception at this statement:boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();

Why?

Comment: @Maxood, it means that there are no active networks.  In other words, the device is not connected to the web.  I'll change the code.

Comment: It only check the network. Not internet. When I tested connecting with a hotspot which doesn't contain mobile data, it return true and my app crashed.

Answer (score 6):

First, you need permission to know whether the device is connected to the web or not. This needs to be in your manifest, in the  element:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

then

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (connec != null && (
    (connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) || 
    (connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))) { 

        //You are connected, do something online.

} else if (connec != null && (
    (connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) ||
    (connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ))) {            

        //Not connected.    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must be connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this permission in your AppManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The method to check if network is available or not:

```
boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
  return isConnected;
}
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html  - CONNECTIVITY_ACTION