# How to write a background service in android to check if device is connected to the internet or not?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android service to check internet connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141807/android-service-to-check-internet-connectivity)

I am designing an Android app to track the total data usage (download+upload).
The app does the following tasks :-

1. Continuously checks if the device is connected to the internet or not.
2. If the device is connected to the internet then start counting the uploaded and           downloaded data.
3. The count is stored in database and displayed to the user for the current session.
4. When the app is installed the service should be started.
5. When the device is rebooted, the service should be started.

I have tried the following code but us this sufficient?

```
public final boolean isInternetOn()
{
    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
    if(     connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED  ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED   ) 
    {
        // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
        //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + â€ connectedâ€, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {

        if(     connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  )
        {
            //System.out.println(â€œNot Connectedâ€);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

-Vaibhav.

Comment: You might want to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789612/how-can-i-check-whether-an-android-device-is-connected-to-the-web)

Comment: Check this [link][1] u might need a broadcaster rather than service


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141807/android-service-to-check-internet-connectivity

Answer (score 3):

> Continuously checks if the device is connected to the internet or not.

Please don't. This is not needed for your use case.

> When the app is installed the service should be started.

This is not supported by Android. It is also not needed for your use case.

> When the device is rebooted, the service should be started.

This is not needed for your use case.

The use of `TrafficStats` does not require an everlasting service. Please simply record values from `TrafficStats` periodically, perhaps using `AlarmManager`, so you do not need to keep stuff in memory all of the time.