# Check network state in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, android-wifi, android-networking

I would like to check Wifi stat in a libGDX project, tried to use code below:

```
   Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener);

    HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener = new  httpResponseListener() {
        public void handleHttpResponse (HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            HttpStatus status = httpResponse.getStatus();
            if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {
                // it was successful
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
        }
    }
```

I added permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

It says `HttpResponseListener cannot resolved`. 
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// there is a small 'h' here, which is wrong ---v
HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener = new httpResponseListener() {
    public void handleHttpResponse (HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        HttpStatus status = httpResponse.getStatus();
        if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {
            // it was successful
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}

// here, you still have the parameter types
Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener);
// this is correct
Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, httpResponseListener);
```

Besides this, this probably won't work. If there is no internet connection, you will not get a response from the server. You have to override [HttpResponseListener.failed()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.HttpResponseListener.html#failed-java.lang.Throwable-).

Comment: Did you actually import the classes? And is your project correctly set up?

Comment: What should httpRequest exactly contains? Where should I put HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener = new httpResponseListener() {...?

Comment: HttpRequest should contain the http method and url. You can use a `HttpRequestBuilder` to create one. And what do you mean by "where should I put it"?

Comment: Can you please attach/link some tutorials? This is the first time, that I work with these....

Comment: I am looking for some simple solutions like this for native android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789612/how-can-i-check-whether-an-android-device-is-connected-to-the-web

Comment: You can use native android: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code